# Getting error while compiling Titanium project within Xcode: -dynamic not specified the following flags are invalid: -ObjC

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, titanium, titanium-mobile

I am getting error for iOS Titanium app.

> Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool: -dynamic not specified the following flags are invalid: -ObjC 
>   error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool: can't locate file for: -lTiCore
>   error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool: file: -lTiCore is not an object file (not allowed in a library)
>   warning: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool: file: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.1.sdk/usr/lib/libiconv.dylib is a dynamic library, not added to the static library
>   warning: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool: file: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.1.sdk/usr/lib/libiconv.dylib is a dynamic library, not added to the static library

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with another (preferably brand new) Ti Project and see if this compiles? If it does compile then it's in your project. Otherwise the solutions below might help.

Have you tried cleaning the project?
Project>Clean... from Titanium studio.

If that does not help delete the contents of DerivedData folder:
Library/Xcode/Developer/DerivedData (delete everything inside)

If that does not help try to switch to another Titanium SDK from your TiApp.xml file.